# Bitbucket (pull request) comment deleted after update

Tags: bitbucket, comments, pull-request

My team and I just start with bitbucket. Also, we review our code now.

Now we noticed that after someone add a comment on a line (for example, "change code...") and the code is changed by the author like the comment said, the comment is deleted in the **overview** section.

Why is that? We only can find the comment back in the **activity** section.

We like to have a confirmation reply from the author after he changed his code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Right now this appears to be common behaviour (at least in the Bitbucket Server version).

You can find an open issue for that in the Bitbucket Issue Tracker. I guess we need to vote for it to get its priority pushed: https://jira.atlassian.com/browse/BSERV-7534